# Why I should not use forceUpdate()

Tags: reactjs

For example I have a store:

```
class MyStore {
  constructor() {
    this.value = 1;
  }
}
```

I need to get and change `MyStore.value` in a view.

I can do it:

```
class MyView extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: MyStore.getValue()
    };
  }
```

And change it:

```
userClick() {
     this.setState({value: MyStore.changeValue('newValue')});
  }
```

Or change `value` in a store and call emit.

But I can do it with `forceUpdate()`:

```
  render() {
     const value = MyStore.value;
     return (
        <div>{value}</div>
     )
  }
```

And change it:

```
userClick() {
     MyStore.value = 'newValue';
     this.forceUpdate();
  }
```

Why is it bad?

Comment: Are you attempting to listen for changes that occur in your store and then update your UI when that occurs?

Comment: @JohnF.  Yes, but I think it's more easy with `forceUpdate`. I don't need to add listeners, etc.

Comment: Your approach should work, but there's no need to maintain a local `state` variable if you're always going to use `MyStore.value` in `render()`. That said, if you choose to use `state.value` in render, then I would go with your first approach, where you call out to `MyStore` to change the value and then setState accordingly.

Comment: @lux, yes, `state.value` is example if I don't use `forceUpdate`. I just can use `MyStore`, change it and call `forceUpdate`. But I'm asking it because I read in the documentation - `Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate()`

Comment: You will _have_ to use `forceUpdate` if you choose to not maintain a local state. By not maintaining a local state you need to manually invoke `render()` on any change, which is what `forceUpdate()` gives you. This is discouraged because `setState` automatically invokes `render()` and maintaining local state is an accepted pattern. I would opt for `this.setState({value: MyStore.changeValue('newValue')});` and then use `state.value` in `render()`

Comment: But If I will use `this.setState({value: MyStore.changeValue('newValue')});` and change `value` in a store too I should change `value` in a store, when call emit, get new states from a store. Extra work...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong in what you are trying to do. You are "just" following basic OO-rules and are encapsulating your data.

Actually I don't understand why most basic React examples don't introduce this pattern, instead of mixing data and presentation. Usually you don't see stuff like *stores* before you reach examples involving, Flux, Redux or MobX (which I think is the way for you to go).

I have rewritten your example in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/plaul/pen/JNbgEN) to use getters and setters and I'm using the observer pattern to notify when data has changed.
I would claim that this (remember it's a quick demo) is a perfectly OK way to use `forceUpdate()`.

```
class MyView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.store.setObserver(this);
  }
  changed(){
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
  render() {
     return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={()=>this.props.store.value = Math.random()}>Change</button>
          <p>{this.props.store.value}</p>
        </div>
     )
  }
}

class MyStore {
  constructor() {
    this._value = 1;
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(val) {
    console.log(val);
    this._value = val;
    this._observer.changed();
  }
  setObserver(observer){
    this._observer = observer;  
  }
}
```

Actually this is what the [mobX library](https://mobx.js.org/) is doing under the surface. It provides you with automatic listener-capacities, and if this is the way you plan to go I definitely advice you to take a look at this library.

It will handle all the "observer" details, including forceUpdate() automatically (it does not use forceUpdate, but calls your render() method when an updata is required).

With mobX the example boilds down to (using a functional component, since it does not need state)

```
var View = observer((props) => (
        <div>
          <button onClick={()=>props.store.value = Math.random()}>Change</button>
          <p>{props.store.value}</p>
        </div>
     )
  )

class MyStore {
  @observable value =1;
  get value() { return this._value; }
  set value(val) { this._value = val; }
}
```

Se live demo on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/plaul/pen/rmjBVG?editors=1111)